# Can my React Router Native setup be improved?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-router

I'm making a Library type of App. My layout is typical... Navbar-Sidebar-MainContent. I have over 100 books, each is it's own component. In my root, in the MainContent section of my layout I have a Switch with routes to all the screens possible for the Main Content section in my app which are well over 100. I also have a Dialer(Orange BTN) in the root so that no matter where the user is they can enter in a Book name and page to jump directly to it (bypassing the UI). I have all the routes as an array in a separate file from which I import into my root(Main.js) as a custom hook and map through them from within the Switch. Is that a typical/efficient setup? Or bad? Performance Wise. Can it be better?

General Navigation

[image: General Navigation]

Dialer in Action

[image: Dialer in Action]

My Route List

```
 [{
        path: "/1Tr",
        component: Tr1,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2Tr",
        component: Tr2,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/3Tr",
        component: Tr3,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/4Tr",
        component: Tr4,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/5Tr",
        component: Tr5,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/6Tr",
        component: Tr6,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/7Tr",
        component: Tr7,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/8Tr",
        component: Tr8,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/9Tr",
        component: Tr9,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/10Tr",
        component: Tr10,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/11Tr",
        component: Tr11,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/12Tr",
        component: Tr12,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/13Tr",
        component: Tr13,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/14Tr",
        component: Tr14,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/15Tr",
        component: Tr15,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/EW",
        component: EW,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/WHR",
        component: WHR,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/FB",
        component: FB,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/GCS",
        component: GCS,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/LV",
        component: LV,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/MCTC",
        component: MCTC,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/MS",
        component: MS,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/SRP",
        component: SRP,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/UAA",
        component: UAA,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG1",
        component: TG1_1,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG2",
        component: TG1_2,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG3",
        component: TG1_3,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG4",
        component: TG1_4,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG5",
        component: TG1_5,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG6",
        component: TG1_6,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG7",
        component: TG1_7,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG8",
        component: TG1_8,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG9",
        component: TG1_9,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG10",
        component: TG1_10,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG11",
        component: TG1_11,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG12",
        component: TG1_12,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG13",
        component: TG1_13,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG14",
        component: TG1_14,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG15",
        component: TG1_15,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG16",
        component: TG1_16,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG17",
        component: TG1_17,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG18",
        component: TG1_18,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG19",
        component: TG1_19,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG20",
        component: TG1_20,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG21",
        component: TG1_21,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG22",
        component: TG1_22,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG23",
        component: TG1_23,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG24",
        component: TG1_24,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG25",
        component: TG1_25,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG26",
        component: TG1_26,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG27",
        component: TG1_27,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG28",
        component: TG1_28,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG29",
        component: TG1_29,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG30",
        component: TG1_30,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG31",
        component: TG1_31,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG32",
        component: TG1_32,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG33",
        component: TG1_33,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG34",
        component: TG1_34,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG35",
        component: TG1_35,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG36",
        component: TG1_36,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG37",
        component: TG1_37,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG38",
        component: TG1_38,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG39",
        component: TG1_39,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG40",
        component: TG1_40,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG41",
        component: TG1_41,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG42",
        component: TG1_42,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG43",
        component: TG1_43,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG44",
        component: TG1_44,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG45",
        component: TG1_45,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG46",
        component: TG1_46,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG47",
        component: TG1_47,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG48",
        component: TG1_48,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG49",
        component: TG1_49,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG50",
        component: TG1_50,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG51",
        component: TG1_51,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1TG52",
        component: TG1_52,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG1",
        component: TG2_1,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG2",
        component: TG2_2,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG3",
        component: TG2_3,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG4",
        component: TG2_4,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG5",
        component: TG2_5,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG6",
        component: TG2_6,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG7",
        component: TG2_7,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG8",
        component: TG2_8,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG9",
        component: TG2_9,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG10",
        component: TG2_10,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG11",
        component: TG2_11,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG12",
        component: TG2_12,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG13",
        component: TG2_13,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG14",
        component: TG2_14,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG15",
        component: TG2_15,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG16",
        component: TG2_16,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG17",
        component: TG2_17,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG18",
        component: TG2_18,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG19",
        component: TG2_19,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG20",
        component: TG2_20,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG21",
        component: TG2_21,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG22",
        component: TG2_22,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG23",
        component: TG2_23,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG24",
        component: TG2_24,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG25",
        component: TG2_25,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG26",
        component: TG2_26,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG27",
        component: TG2_27,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG28",
        component: TG2_28,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG29",
        component: TG2_29,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG30",
        component: TG2_30,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG31",
        component: TG2_31,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG32",
        component: TG2_32,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG33",
        component: TG2_33,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG34",
        component: TG2_34,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG35",
        component: TG2_35,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG36",
        component: TG2_36,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG37",
        component: TG2_37,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG38",
        component: TG2_38,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG39",
        component: TG2_39,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG40",
        component: TG2_40,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG41",
        component: TG2_41,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG42",
        component: TG2_42,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG43",
        component: TG2_43,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG44",
        component: TG2_44,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG45",
        component: TG2_45,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2TG46",
        component: TG2_46,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1Ans",
        component: Ans1,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2Ans",
        component: Ans2,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/3Ans",
        component: Ans3,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/4Ans",
        component: Ans4,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/5Ans",
        component: Ans5,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1JL",
        component: JL1,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2JL",
        component: JL2,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/3JL",
        component: JL3,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/4JL",
        component: JL4,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/5JL",
        component: JL5,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/6JL",
        component: JL6,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/7JL",
        component: JL7,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/8JL",
        component: JL8,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/9JL",
        component: JL9,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC1",
        component: SC1_1,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC2",
        component: SC1_2,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC3",
        component: SC1_3,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC4",
        component: SC1_4,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC5",
        component: SC1_5,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC6",
        component: SC1_6,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC7",
        component: SC1_7,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC8",
        component: SC1_8,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },

    {
        path: "/1SC9",
        component: SC1_9,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC10",
        component: SC1_10,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC11,12",
        component: SC1_11_12,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC13",
        component: SC1_13,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC14",
        component: SC1_14,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC15",
        component: SC1_15,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC16",
        component: SC1_16,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC17",
        component: SC1_17,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SC18",
        component: SC1_18,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2SC1",
        component: SC2_1,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2SC2",
        component: SC2_2,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2SC3,4",
        component: SC2_3_4,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2SC5,6",
        component: SC2_5_6,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2SC7,8",
        component: SC2_7_8,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2SC9",
        component: SC2_9,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2SC10",
        component: SC2_10,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2SC11",
        component: SC2_11,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/3SC1",
        component: SC3_1,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/3SC2",
        component: SC3_2,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/3SC3,4",
        component: SC3_3_4,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/3SC5,6",
        component: SC3_5_6,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/3SC7",
        component: SC3_7,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/3SC8-10",
        component: SC3_8_10,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/3SC11,12",
        component: SC3_11_12,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/4SC1-3",
        component: SC4_1_3,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/4SC4-9",
        component: SC4_4_9,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/4SC10-12",
        component: SC4_10_12,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/5SC1-5",
        component: SC5_1_5,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/5SC6-12",
        component: SC5_6_12,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/6SC1-6",
        component: SC6_1_6,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/6SC7-12",
        component: SC6_7_12,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/7SC1-6",
        component: SC7_1_6,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/7SC7-12",
        component: SC7_7_12,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/8SC1-12",
        component: SC8_1_12,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/9SC1-12",
        component: SC9_1_12,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/10SC1",
        component: SC10_1,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/10SC2",
        component: SC10_2,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },       
    {
        path: "/13SC11,12",
        component: SC13_11_12,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/1SR",
        component: SR1,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/2SR",
        component: SR2,
        itemProps: {
            exact: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/",
        component: Home,
        previousScreen: "/",
        itemProps: {
            exact: true
        }
    },
]
```

The Layout in my Root

```
<View>          
        <View>
/*MAINCONTENT*/
          <Switch>
            {routesList.map((item, index) => <Route path={item.path} key={index} render={() => <item.component {...item.itemProps} />} />)}
          </Switch>
        </View>
/*NAVBAR*/
        <View>
          <Navbar/>
        </View>         
/*SIDEBAR*/
      <NativeRouter>
        <Sidebar/>
      </NativeRouter>
    </View>
```

Comment: More or less I have been using the same approach and havent found anything better than this yet. It simply works without too much fuss. Just one thing about `item.component`, component names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: @Ajay Thank you for the comment, I wasn't sure if that's how typically people did it, now I know!